# Hadoop: MapReduce job giving java library error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera-quickstart-vm

When I am running any MapReduce job in Cloudera VM, below warning is occurring 4-5 times in continues manner. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
16/11/06 00:47:38 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception  
java.lang.InterruptedException  
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)  
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:862)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:600)  
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:789)
```

Occurring in the middle of the execution of sqoop jobs created. But not when hive job get executed.

Comment: I have been using cloudera VM but never observed this issue. Just once again, can you please confirm that this warning comes while storing the file inside HDFS or during Job execution? Did you try running the same Job with some other different file? 

Or maybe can try this command: hdfs fsck <file_name> -files -blocks -locations -racks to see whether there is any issue from HDFS storage.

Comment: 16/11/11 07:18:38 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of products 16/11/11 07:18:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address 16/11/11 07:18:39 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar 16/11/11 07:18:41 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps 16/11/11 07:18:41 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032---> after this, above error occurs 6 times in row.. before execution of job..HDFS luks gud